# systemd service - udp broadcast can't reach other machine

Tags: centos, systemd, socket, udp

I have a service located under /usr/lib/systemd/system. This service runs the app that i've been developing (.net core 2.0). Same app runs on different machines (centos7 both). They use udp sockets to find each other.

I've been testing this app for a very long time before i prepare *.service* file for them and everything was working great. They were able to broadcast messages to one another.

When the service runs the application, the only message that instance can get is the one that same instance was broadcasting in the first place. Same situation on the other machines. They can get their own broadcasts but not the other one's.

Since i'm new on linux and not sure where to look and what should i search, i came accross some useless information and that is why i need some help here.

Thanks

---

.service file contents

```
[Unit]
Description=Apix

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/apix
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /APIX/Apix.dll

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When i start the app myself, i can see the udp-port is being used by dotnet. But when the service runs the app, this line disappears.

```
netstat -lntup
udp    0   0 0.0.0.0:14235    0.0.0.0:*     11319/dotnet
```

Comment: CentOS 7 enables SELinux in its factory default settings. Any processes started from a root login session will automatically be labeled with the `unconfined_t` SELinux type, causing them to be unrestricted by default - but processes started by `systemd` service may have a different labeling. Run `ps Zax | grep [d]otnet` to find the dotnet process and see its SELinux label. Do it both when the process is started by the service and when started manually - is the label different?

Comment: @telcoM yes they are. with service: system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 1917 ? SLsl |||||| with manual: unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 2104 pts/0 SLl+. So what does that mean?

Comment: @telcoM somehow it is not about selinux after all. somehow it worked when i disabled selinux the first time but now i am back where i started. i cant get udp messages from the service even if selinux is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

[Dan Walsh's Livejournal from 2014](https://danwalsh.livejournal.com/70577.html) has a description of `unconfined_service_t`, although it's so heavy in SELinux jargon that I'm afraid you might not get much out of it at your current SELinux knowledge level.

As per your comments, the SELinux labels for the process were:

- when started with a .service file: `system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0`
- when started manually: `unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023`

SELinux labels have four parts:

- SELinux user (with the `_u` suffix)
- SELinux role (with the `_r` suffix)
- SELinux type (with the `_t` suffix)
- and a SELinux level definition, which is only used with a full *Multi-Level Security* SELinux policy (military security and the like), not with the default *targeted* policy.

In the SELinux default policy, the SELinux user identifier is distinct from your regular username: in effect, SELinux does not care about exactly whom any files or processes belong to, only about whether you are an essential system process or something started by one (`system_u`), an administrator (`sysadm_u`), a regular user (`user_u`), or something that has been specified as unrestricted by the SELinux policy (`unconfined_u`).

The role part can be used to specify several "partial-administrator" roles, like `dbadm_r` for data base administration, or `logadm_r` for access to system logs.

The most important part regarding the *targeted* SELinux policy is the type specification, or the part with the `_t` suffix.

`unconfined_service_t` should be an unrestricted type, so I'm uncertain what goes wrong there. Perhaps the files under `/APIX/` directory tree are all unlabelled, and that might be causing the problems?

Like processes, files should also have a SELinux label, viewable with `ls -Z`. In general, SELinux gives a `default_t` for any files that have no label specified. When faced with `default_t`, SELinux "thinks": "I don't know what this is; it might be Ultra Top Secret that has lost its label, so let's keep it extra secure until some admin tells us the proper label for it." In short, `default_t` is something you'll need to fix.

Files will normally inherit the labeling of the directory they're in at creation time, unless there is a SELinux rule specified that says otherwise. But if you make a new top-level directory like `/APIX`, you'll need to decide how to label it, or else you end up with `default_t`, which may cause problems.

You might try setting `semanage permissive -a unconfined_service_t`: it allows any services using `unconfined_service_t` free access, while still logging any SELinux policy violations to `/var/log/auth/` as if SELinux was fully enabled for them. Then running `audit2why` on the relevant part of the audit log should give you a clearer description of why SELinux is blocking the program from doing something it wants to do.

The correct fix might be simply labelling the `/APIX/` directory with a suitable filesystem label.

Comment: i have tried to change default_t labels and i tried a few. rebooted the machine. nothing changed. soo, i tried 'semanage permissive' command after that. rebooted the machine. nothing changed. but i am learning so much, which is great and i am really grateful for your help.